# C# Equivalent of Python's itertools.cycle

Tags: c#

am trying to write similar code in c#

```
userdata_ = open(user_data.txt)
userdata = userdata_.readlines()
userdata_.close()
userdata = iter(map(lambda x: x.strip(), userdata))
userdata = itertools.cycle(userdata

)
```

now I can use this userdata like a generator and call Next(userdata)
to get the next value
in infinite loop

Comment: Do you expect it to turn over after the last record?

Comment: yes in never-ending loop cycle

Comment: Do you expect to know if the file changed between iterations?

Comment: no am just trying to get data in sequence

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Python user. If this works the way I think it does it's not built into C# directly, but you can write a simple (or at least brief) helper method for C# method to get the same kind of result:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Cycle(this IList<T> items)
{
    while(true) foreach(T item in items) yield return item;
}
```

And then use it with a file like this:

```
var userdata = File.ReadAllLines("user_data.txt").Cycle();
```

Note this requires loading the entire file into memory, which might be a problem for larger files. We can do better by combining this all into one method:

```
public IEnumerable<string> CycleFile(string fileName)
{
   while (true) foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(fileName)) yield return line;
}
```

This will only ever try to load one line into memory at a time, and has the added advantage of re-opening the file after each time through. You may want to check how file system locking works for this scenario, though. Reading the file in a shared mode may require a little more work (StreamReader with the right FileMode rather than just File.ReadLines()).

As with any `IEnumerable`, you can use the underlying `Enumerator` object directly. Here's an example:

```
var userdata = File.ReadAllLines("user_data.txt").Cycle().GetEnumerator();
while (true)
{ 
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    userdata.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine(userdata.Current);
}
```

Comment: thankyou i just test it it's work fine but is there is way to call it without loop like in python
'''Next(userdata)```
give next data in list

Comment: @hkrat See the update at the end of the answer.

Comment: thankyou sir without your help it ll be hard for me

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the [`GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator?view=net-5.0) method which returns an enumerator which can be used to attempt to retrieve the next value in the sequence until the end is reached.

```cs
IEnumerable<string> userdata = GetUserData();
IEnumerator userdataEnumerator = userdata.GetEnumerator();

do
{
   string cur = userdataEnumerator.Current;
   // do something with cur
}
while (userdataEnumerator.MoveNext());
```